# Convert the IP Address range to two BIGINT for faster lookup

Tags: mysql, java

I am working on a project in which we need to do `IP Address lookups`. So for this we have got the datasets which will look like below and now the next steps is to populate this datasets in to the `MySql table`. Below is the dataset example containing columns-

```
ip_address      country region  city           metro-code   latitude    longitude   postal-code   country-code   region-code    city-code   continent-code  country-code

24.32.116.116   usa       tx    clarksville    623           33.6103    -95.0498    75426            840           44             34918            6            us
65.29.108.232   usa       mi    novi           505           42.4637    -83.4604    48375            840           23             4339             6            us
66.169.99.69    usa       tx    ft worth       623           32.7016    -97.3823    76109            840           44             771              6            us
72.70.100.111   usa       ma    peabody        506           42.5332    -70.9726    1960             840           22             1392             6            us
174.252.116.137 usa       va    oakton         511           38.8892    -77.3222    22124            840           47             3860             6            us
68.55.144.242   usa       md    pasadena       512           39.1276    -76.5125    21122            840           21             4358             6            us
174.252.83.27   usa       pa    lancaster      566           40.0459    -76.3542    17603            840           39             333              6            us
174.78.192.31   usa       ga    warner robins  503           32.5958    -83.6384    31088            840           11             5052             6            us
98.192.146.235  usa       fl    panama city    656           30.1804    -85.5598    32404            840           10             671              6            us
71.192.181.20   usa       ma    springfield    543           42.1187    -72.5483    1109             840           22             967              6            us
76.183.54.227   usa       tx    dallas         623           32.7202    -96.6769    75217            840           44             77               6            us
69.62.143.140   usa       ca    granite bay    862           38.7442    -121.191    95746            840           5              49451            6            us
69.142.76.32    usa       nj    penns grove    504           39.707     -75.4467    8069             840           31             2335             6            us
70.173.54.93    usa       nv    las vegas      839           36.2059    -115.225    89108            840           29             173              6            us
98.242.8.222    usa       ca    fresno         866           36.7968    -119.883    93722            840           5              19               6            us
```

**Problem Statement:-**

I am planning to store the `START_IP_NUM` and `END_IP_NUM` as `BIGINT` in the MySql database instead of storing `IP Address` in the table as doing a lookup against a BIGINT is far faster than searching a string (dotted ip notation).

So my question is we will be having separate `Java Program` that will populate the above datasets in the MySql table. So I need to device some sort of logic which can convert the above datasets into like below-

```
start_ip_num
end_ip_num
country 
region  
city           
metro-code  
latitude    
longitude   
postal-code   
country-code     
region-code 
city-code   
continent-code  
country-code
```

I am confuse given a IP Address how should I device `start_ip_num` and `end_ip_num` here and store it into the `MySql table`

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your requirements correctly.

From the dataset provided the `start_ip_num` and `end_ip_num` will be the same.

Why you may ask? you are not storing a range of ip addresses; take for example a /24 range: `192.168.1.0/24` this provides a range 192.168.1.0 - 192.168.1.255, whilst really only ip's `192.168.1.1` though `192.168.1.254` are usable (.255 being the broadcast).

If you are storing a 'range' the start and end values will differ

```
mysql> select INET_ATON('192.168.1.1') as start_ip_num, INET_ATON('192.168.1.254') as end_ip_num;
+--------------+------------+
| start_ip_num | end_ip_num |
+--------------+------------+
|   3232235777 | 3232236030 |
+--------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If not they will be the same, if you want the ranges for each a `whois 24.32.116.116` will reveal this information.

e.g.

24.32.116.116 has 
24.32.0.0/16

and 
24.32.116.0/22  "Comment:        Clarksville, Tx Customers"

The later providing the required information.

As such your 'range' is strictly speaking: 24.32.116.0 - 24.32.119.255

```
mysql> select INET_ATON('24.32.116.0') as start_ip_num, INET_ATON('24.32.116.255') as end_ip_num;
+--------------+------------+
| start_ip_num | end_ip_num |
+--------------+------------+
|    404780032 |  404780287 |
+--------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```